# Overwrite Image from 'FileTransfer.download' Using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, filesystems

I have a phonegap Android app which downloads images from the server using the `FileTransfer` element. I save the image in the `root.fullPath + "/namefile.jpg"`.
Then, if the application is online I save the image and then set the `src` attribute of the image to the source of the image in the file system, and if it is offline I get the image from the filesystem directly.

The problem is in this situation; when the image changes in the server, I download it again but it still shows the old image. Then if I close the app and open it again it loads the correct new changed image.

Here is the code

```
ft.download(
    uri,
    fs.root.fullPath+"/filename",
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        urlNuevo=entry.fullPath;
        $("#my_image").attr("src",entry.fullPath);//here is the problem it still shows the previous version of the image
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        urlNuevo= fs.root.fullPath+"/filename"
        $("#my_image").attr("src",fs.root.fullPath+"/filename");
    }

);
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? Did the random number assignment work for this?

Answer (score 1):

The browser is caching the image based on url.

This will also happen if you do the same thing with a local html file with desktop Safari, and manually swap out the image file. Unless you hit reload, and just simply visit the page again, the browser will use the cached version.

You can make the image url unique by adding a random query parameter, which is otherwise ignored/harmless. If you have some way of tracking revisions or modified date, use that instead.

```
<img id="i" src="test.png" />
<script>
document.getElementById("i").src += "?_r=" + Math.random();
</script>
```